# Android Temperature Converter Not Functioning?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using the vogella tutorial, and I'm almost positive I followed the instructions exactly, but when I try to use the app, it doesn't function, it only shows the xml layout.

Code:

```
package convert.activity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ConvertActivityActivity extends Activity {
private EditText text;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    text = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

}

// This method is called at button click because we assigned the name to the
// "On Click property" of the button
public void myClickHandler(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
    case R.id.button1: 
        RadioButton celsiusButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio0);
        RadioButton fahrenheitButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radio1);
        if (text.getText().length() == 0) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter a valid number",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }

        float inputValue = Float.parseFloat(text.getText().toString());
        if (celsiusButton.isChecked()) {
            text.setText(String
                    .valueOf(convertFahrenheitToCelsius(inputValue)));
            celsiusButton.setChecked(false);
            fahrenheitButton.setChecked(true);
        } else {
            text.setText(String
                    .valueOf(convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(inputValue)));
            fahrenheitButton.setChecked(false);
            celsiusButton.setChecked(true);
        }
        break;
    }
}

// Converts to celsius 
private float convertFahrenheitToCelsius(float fahrenheit) {
    return ((fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9);
}

// Converts to fahrenheit
private float convertCelsiusToFahrenheit(float celsius) {
    return ((celsius * 9) / 5) + 32;
}
}
```

What on earth could possibly be wrong with it?
(The public class ConvevrtActivityActivity is it's actual name)

EDIT: Here's my XML too:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<EditText android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" ></EditText>

<RadioGroup android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="@string/celsius" >
</RadioButton>

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fahrenheit" >
</RadioButton>
</RadioGroup>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/calc" >
</Button>  


</LinearLayout>
```

LOGCAT:

```
02-08 21:05:39.392: W/ThrottleService(89): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
02-08 21:07:18.561: D/dalvikvm(172): GC_CONCURRENT freed 385K, 6% free 9529K/10119K,         paused 9ms+8ms
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89): problem reading network stats
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem   parsing idx 1
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at    com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.jav    a:300)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at   com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.jav    a:250)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at     com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.getNetworkStatsDetailGroupedByUid(BatteryStatsImpl    .java:5734)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.access$100(BatteryStatsImpl.java:76)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at  com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.computeCurrentTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImp    l.java:2457)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at  com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl$Uid.getTcpBytesReceived(BatteryStatsImpl.java:2446 )
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeSummaryToParcel(BatteryStatsImpl.java:5437)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4836)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at com.android.internal.os.BatteryStatsImpl.writeAsyncLocked(BatteryStatsImpl.java:4818)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.updateCpuStatsNow(ActivityManagerService.java:1649)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService$3.run(ActivityManagerService.java:1531)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException:    /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>  (FileInputStream.java:78)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.jav    a:269)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     ... 10 more
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open   failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native  Method)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at  libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
02-08 21:12:06.030: A/BatteryStatsImpl(89):     ... 12 more
02-08 21:12:06.439: D/dalvikvm(89): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1446K, 16% free 11329K/13383K,     paused 10ms+19ms
02-08 21:14:45.149: D/dalvikvm(172): GC_CONCURRENT freed 383K, 6% free 9529K/10119K,  paused 8ms+7ms
02-08 21:15:39.493: W/ThrottleService(89): unable to find stats for iface rmnet0
```

Comment: post your xml too. And add some log statements in your click handler callback so that you can tell if you are even getting any callbacks.

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong in the log, but if it helps, I'm using a real phone as an emulator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you haven't "tied" your click listener method to your button view. Change that portion of your layout to look like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/calc" 
    android:onClick="myClickHandler">
</Button>
```

If you don't recognize any of that stuff from the log it is probably unrelated to your application. What I meant was to put log statements into your java that will basically print to the log cat. That way you can use them to figure out where your applications are breaking while you are building them. something like this:

```
Log.d("TAG","I'm inside the click callback!");
```

Comment: Thank you SO much! I completely forgot about that.